# Use grep to exactly match a string in text inside files and then move those files to a separate directory

Tags: bash, grep, mv

I have several files inside a directory, some which contain the word "sweet". I would like to use grep to find the files which contain the exact word and then move them to a different folder.

This is my code :

```
mv `grep -lir 'sweet' ~/directory1/` ~/directory2
```

However, there are some files with the word "sweets" or "sweeter" or "Sweet", my command is moving them as well, whereas I want the match to be strictly "sweet".

Please help, thanks.

Comment: `grep -lirwF ...`?

Comment: @Shawn sorry, it did not work..I am using, grep -w "sweet" * | wc -l , to check where and how many times it is occuring, I see its only 3 times in 3 files. However using grep -lir or grep -lirwF shows some other files as well having the strings "Sweet" etc.

Comment: @ Shawn : using grep -lrwF worked !

Comment: If you want case-sensitive matching, why are you using `-i`?

Comment: Note: use `$(....)` for command substitution instead of using *backticks*. Far easier to read and less likely to mess up.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep -lrwF works

check comment thread with Shawn